# EventLogSession instantiation fails with .NET Core 3.0.0-preview8

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to read windows logs of the remote machine using .NET Core 3.0.0-preview8 version as the documents support EventLogSession from .NET Core 3.0.0-preview8. But when I am running the sample code snippet to create a session from EventLogSession it failed at runtime below is the stacktrace

Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPermissionHolder.GetEventLogPermission()
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession..ctor(String server, String domain, String user, SecureString password, SessionAuthentication logOnType)
   at WincTest1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\JIRA\Framework\WincModernisation\WincTest1\Program.cs:line 37

Please refer
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25ba2c85-c0bc-418c-8261-84dbeaf7aa92/eventlogsession-instantiation-fails-with-net-core-300preview8?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: try .NET Core 3.0.0 Preview9

Comment: @magicandre1981 Still the same :(

Comment: @magicandre1981 below is .csproj file looks like `code`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Core" Version="3.5.21022.801" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>`code`

Comment: @magicandre1981 any package reference, I am missing here?

Comment: try also preview9 of EventLog: **<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.6.0-preview9.19421.4" />**

Comment: @magicandre1981  Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: EventLog access is not supported on this platform.        Yeah It worked when I run it on visual studio on windows. But the same code didn't work on Linux environment.             I was actually trying to read the windows event logs from the linux remote host.

Comment: [report it to Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues)

Comment: @magicandre1981 [Created a issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40925)